# Cuda multiplication of an m-by-n matrix in an n-by-1 vector

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

The following kernel multiplies two n-by-n matrices:

```
    __global__ void matrixMultiplication(const double *A, const double *B, double *C, int N)
{
    int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    double value = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++){
    value += A[k * N + j] * B[i * N + k];
    }
    C[i * N + j] = value;
    }
```

I use the above kernel in MATLAB like this:

```
k = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('matrixMultiplication.ptx', 'matrixMultiplication.cu');
A = rand(3,4);
b = rand(4,1);
C = zeros(3,1);
k.ThreadBlockSize = [3,4,1];
k.GridSize = [1, 1];
D = A*b;
C = feval(k,A,b,C,4);
D-C
```

but the result is not zero!  How can I change this kernel so that I can multiply an m-by-n matrix in an n-by-1 vector?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything

Comment: @talonmied but the result I get is different from normal multiplication!

Comment: That kernel is designed to be run with CUDA thread per entry in the output matrix. The only thing that could possibly be changed is the indexing calculations within the kernel and that would depend on the byte order that the matrix is stored in (which you haven't said anything about)

Comment: @talonmied Thanks a lot for answering... but since I'm new to CUDA, I would really appreciate it if you could explain a bit more or share a link to a similar question. I have also edited my question and added more information.

Comment: @talonmied, I changed the k.ThreadBlockSize from [3,4,1] to [3,1,1] but still D-C is not a zero vector! as I understand the size of the problem is small and requires no more than one grid so I didn't change the grid size. please correct my mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

Because it transpires you are using Matlab (and arrays are stored in column major order), you will have to make a very minor modification to the kernel code:

```
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void matrixMultiplication(const double *A, const double *B, double *C, int M, int N)
{
    int i = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    double value = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++){
        value += A[k * M + j] * B[i * M + k];
    }
    C[i * N + j] = value;
}

int main()
{
    const int M = 3, N = 4, K = 1;
    thrust::device_vector<double> A(M*N), B(N*K), C(M*K);

    thrust::counting_iterator<double> counter(1.0);
    thrust::copy(counter, counter + (M*N), A.begin());
    thrust::copy(counter, counter + (N*K), B.begin());

    dim3 grid(1,1), block(M,K);

    matrixMultiplication<<<grid, block>>>( thrust::raw_pointer_cast(A.data()),
                                           thrust::raw_pointer_cast(B.data()),
                                           thrust::raw_pointer_cast(C.data()),
                                           M, N );

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i=0; i<M*K; i++)
        std::cout << C[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The kernel requires one thread per entry in the output matrix, so you will need to run 3 x 1 threads in you (3 x 4) * (4 x 1) example. When run you should see this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o spoonfull spoonfull.cu 
$ ./spoonfull 
70
80
90
```

which is correct for column major order storage.

Comment: Thanks a million, I just changed the kernel and tested it in MATLAB... it works perfectly ... you are the best... by the way which source do you suggest to learn CUDA for those who don't have much C/C++/C# experience?

Comment: some good info about learning CUDA can be found here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-learn-CUDA